# Compiling vim 7.3 with python and perl support on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: python, linux, vim

I compiled vim 7.3 with

```
./configure --enable-gnome-check --enable-cscope --with-features=huge --enable-perlinterp \
--enable- ythoninterp --enable-rubyinterp --enable-multibyte --enable-python3interp \
--with-compiledby=tahoang@something.com
```

on Ubuntu 11.04 in order to have proper indentation and syntax highlighting. However, python, perl and ruby don't seem to be linking correctly as shown below:

```
Compilation: 
gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -Wall -g -O2  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      

Linking: 
gcc   -Wl,--as-needed -o vim       -lm -lncurses -lselinux   -lacl -lgpm
```

Am I missing some critical points here? Following is output from vim --version on other machine with vim installed properly with python and perl support.

```
Compilation: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
-march=x86-64 -msse3 -O2 -pipe -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
-I/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux/CORE  -I/usr/include/python2.6
-pthread   

Linking: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc   -rdynamic  -Wl,-O1 -L/usr/local/lib
-o vim       -lcurses -lacl -rdynamic
-L/usr/local/lib64 /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux/auto/DynaLoader/DynaLoader.a -L/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux/CORE -lperl -lutil -lc -L/usr/lib/python2.6/config -lpython2.6 -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic
```

Thanks! Please let me know if I can provide any other information to elaborate on the issue.

---

Following is output from make that belongs to link.sh

```
link.sh: Using auto/link.sed file to omit a few libraries

gcc -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu    -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -L/usr/local/lib         -o vim objects/buffer.o objects/blowfish.o objects/charset.o objects/diff.o objects/digraph.o objects/edit.o objects/eval.o objects/ex_cmds.o objects/ex_cmds2.o objects/ex_docmd.o objects/ex_eval.o objects/ex_getln.o objects/fileio.o objects/fold.o objects/getchar.o objects/hardcopy.o objects/hashtab.o  objects/if_cscope.o objects/if_xcmdsrv.o objects/main.o objects/mark.o objects/memfile.o objects/memline.o objects/menu.o objects/message.o objects/misc1.o objects/misc2.o objects/move.o objects/mbyte.o objects/normal.o objects/ops.o objects/option.o objects/os_unix.o objects/pathdef.o objects/popupmnu.o objects/quickfix.o objects/regexp.o objects/screen.o objects/search.o objects/sha256.o objects/spell.o objects/syntax.o  objects/tag.o objects/term.o objects/ui.o objects/undo.o objects/window.o objects/gui.o objects/gui_gtk.o objects/gui_gtk_x11.o objects/pty.o objects/gui_gtk_f.o objects/gui_beval.o    objects/if_python.o objects/py_config.o   objects/if_ruby.o   objects/netbeans.o  objects/version.o   -pthread -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0   -lXt -lncurses -liconv     -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lutil -Xlinker -export-dynamic   -lruby1.8 -lrt -lm
link.sh: Linked fine with a few libraries omitted
```

Comment: What is the linkers error message  ?

Comment: I am working on it. Re compiling :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on Ubuntu 11.04 in order to have proper indentation and syntax highlighting`

You don't need to link Python, Ruby, or Perl to get syntax highlighting or indentation in Vim.
They're only used to run Python/Ruby/Perl code inside Vim.

Comment: So how to get automatic indentation in Vim for python?

Comment: @Tanner: I'd guess `syntax on`, `filetype plugin on` and `filetype indent on` in your $MYVIMRC